# Gulp upload ftp after watch finished

Tags: ftp, gulp

Here's my gulp file. It should compile scss and upload file after change. It uploads, but not always. What am I doing wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    gutil = require( 'gulp-util' ),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    ftp = require( 'vinyl-ftp' );

gulp.task( 'deploy', function () {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'host',
        user:     'user@host',
        password: 'pass',
        parallel: 10,
        log:      gutil.log
    } );

    var globs = [
        'src/**',
        'css/**',
        'build/**',
        'js/**',
        'fonts/**',
        'index.html'
    ];

    // using base = '.' will transfer everything to /public_html correctly
    // turn off buffering in gulp.src for best performance

    return gulp.src( globs, { base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.newer( '/test' ) ) // only upload newer files
        .pipe( conn.dest( '/test' ) );

} );

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function (){
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['css', 'deploy']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['css', 'deploy']);
```

This **does not** run the `css` task followed by the `deploy` task. Gulp executes all tasks with maximum concurrency unless you tell it otherwise.

That means your `css` and `deploy` tasks both start running immediately whenever a `.scss` file is changed. Depending on whether your `css` task finishes compiling your `.scss` files before your `deploy` task starts transmitting them, this might work or it might not.

You need to tell gulp to execute the `deploy` task only **after** the `css` task has finished:

```
gulp.task( 'deploy', ['css'], function () {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is beautiful :) I've made gist in case someone's interested https://gist.github.com/arysom/9ab1bfd670d0be1e8899ac45ea6b432f